# What are those black dots on microchips?

Tags: raspberry-pi

I just noticed those black dots on various microchips and asked me for what they are.

For Example on the Raspberry Pi 3B+ or the BME680.

Comment: Your new to Stack Overflow.  This is not really a programming question. There are some other groups just like this, one in fact specifically for Rasberry Pi. Also a pic would help your post on any group.

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/search?q=package+dot

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to https://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are asking about the pin 1 markings on IC packages. These marks allow the correct orientation of the device when it is being soldered to the board.